# How to add an id to markers if it's not built into the gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I grabbed the code from the wiki for "Adding an id to markers and access them later."

It looks like this:

```
markers = ... // Fetch markers
Gmaps.store.markers = markers.map(function(m) {
  marker = handler.addMarker(m);
  marker.serviceObject.set('id', m.id); // You can add other attributes using set
  return marker;
});
handler.bounds.extendWith(Gmaps.store.markers);
handler.fitMapToBounds();
```

In my controller, I tried adding the **id** to the available attributes for the map markers

```
 def map_markers model
   Gmaps4rails.build_markers(model) do |item, marker|
     marker.lat item.lat
     marker.lng item.long

     marker.id item.id

     marker.picture marker_picture(:real_estate)
     marker.infowindow string
   end
 end
```

I kept getting an error because id is not an attribute made available to the build_markers method. You can only set lat, lng, title, infowindow, and picture according to https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/gmaps4rails/2.0.4/symbols/Gmaps4rails::MarkersBuilder#line=21

How do you pass the **id** to the view for each marker if you can't do it by default in the `Gmaps4rails.build_markers` method?

Comment: what about `marker.id =  m.id;` instead of `marker.serviceObject.set('id', m.id);`

Comment: and server side: `marker.json({ id: item.id})`

Comment: for the records: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Json-builder

Answer (score 1):

As told [in the wiki](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Json-builder), you can add your own json stuff through a hash like:

```
marker.json({ id: item.id})
```